# setInterval Variable Scope

Tags: javascript

I have a variable declared at the top of my function as `this.current_test = null;` and then down the line I have a setInterval function and I need to set the variable to a new parameter...

`this.current_test.failed = true;`

Code:

```
timer = this.window.setInterval(function() 
   {
      this.window.clearInterval(timer);
      this.current_test.failed = true;
   },1000);
 }
```

However I am getting a `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'this.current_test.failed = true'` error

And I assume this is because this.current_test is not defined inside the setInterval function, so how can I edit that variable?

Comment: Can you post more of your code? Specifically, the part where you define `current_test`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope of your 'this' in the timer function will not refer to this.window. this scope is that for function only what you can do

```
var wnd=this.window; // take your widow to local variable
timer = this.window.setInterval(function() 
{
   this.window.clearInterval(timer);
   wnd.current_test.failed = true; // use your local variabe in the function
   },1000);
}
```

By the way for reffering to window why do you need 'this' and also the if cuurent_test is a global variable then you can declare like

```
var current_test;
```

and you can use the global variable inside the timer function